# Is there a way to set a shader define in Löve?

Tags: shaders, love2d

I know I can use shader:send() to change variables, but is there a way to set/change a #define?

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Shaders don't really work that way. Once the shader is compiled, any instance of the name you defined will be replaced with its value. If you want something that changes throughout your program, use a variable.

Comment: Can you suggest a way that OP can set the #define and compile a new version of the shader with that configuration?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that. However, you can prepend a `#define` macro to the shader code when creating the shader.